# Is there any way to automatically deserialize different Json string to different structure vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I'm working a project that need do deserialize json send from server using VB.net. problem is the server may send different json structure with a same address time to time.
So I'm wondering is there any way to deserialize those Json to diffent structures.

Sample like: 
Json1:

```
{"Success":1,
  "ID":123456,
  "Action":{
     "Type":"Battle"
     "Damage":555
     "DropItems":[
         {"Name":"name1","Type":"weapon"},
         {"Name":"name2","Type":"weapon"}]}}
```

Json2:

```
{"Success":1,
  "ID":123456,
  "Action":{
     "MaxCount":
     "ItemName":"SampleItem"
     "Description":"Some description string"}}
```

These are just samples, there are much more diffent Json to deal with. but "Success" and "Action" attribute will be allways be there.

Comment: You would have to walk through the JSON programatically using something like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to determine what class structure to deserialize it in to.  It would be better if the server returned some kind of discriminator to help you know what kind of object it it.

Comment: why does the server do this? The response should be consistent, unless there's an error. At the very least, the structure of the response should be predictable based on some input that you gave it, or some other measurable thing (I don't know, like time of day or something that anyone can discover). Is that the case here? Does the output structure vary predictably based on the input you send? If so then you can know how to deserialize your object based on that, since you already know what inputs you sent.

Comment: If not, then there is arguably a design problem with the API. It should either behave predictably, or return a metadata property to tell you what the type of object is. If even that's not possible then you may need to define a class which holds all the known possible fields, with some of them only filled optionally, depending on the JSON returned. Or, you could walk the JSON manually in your code to discover what properties are there, and use the structure you discover to decide how to deserialize it.

Comment: Good idea, `a class which holds all the known possible fields`

Comment: @djv thanks. IMHO though this suggestion is really just a workaround for a poorly designed API. Fixing the API should be the ideal solution.

Comment: @ADyson I'm making a applation that intercept transaction, that can view infomations(of a game). respond body change depends on the request body, but intercept request body is not allowed.So I have no way to Identfy the respond body. and make a class that holds all possible fields would make my code nearly unreadable becuse there's like 50+ diffrent respond body exist. Maybe I could use Dynmic Json to make dynmic object and then cast it to structure I premade. Is that possiable?

Comment: @ADyson _walk the JSON manually in your code to discover what properties are there, and use the structure you discover to decide how to deserialize it._ Would help I think. DynmicJson may don't work the way I think it will.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to intercept someone else's communication?

Comment: @ADyson pretty much so, I'm trying to intercept a web browser game communication. The publisher of the game says intercept and change request is not allowed but they didn't say I can't do it to the respond.So I'm trying.

Comment: `respond body change depends on the request body`  which means you *do* have a way to know what you get back (as per comment #2)

Comment: @Plutonix Do that would be a violation to the agreement of that game.

Comment: Nonsense.  If you request Foo, you know you are going to get a FooResponse.  If you post a Bar, you know you are going to get a BarResponse.  You can deserialize accordingly.

Comment: I may have resloved this,I may have resolved this,I declare two event to deal with this. when json received I use DynamicJson make a object as a eventarg and raise event1.every premaded structure have a method to handle event1 and look through Json object if it match my structure then return a instance of the structure then raise event2 with it as return.  Thanks every body!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(String, JsonSerializerSettings)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_1.htm) to attempt deserialization.

First, make a C# class for each response. It should have all of the member variables that appear in the JSON. (i.e `Action`, `Battle`, etc all formatted in the data structures specified in the JSON)

Create a [`JsonSerializerSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) object and set [`MissingMemberHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MissingMemberHandling.htm) to `Error`, so that an exception is thrown when serialization fails.

Catch that exception and try again with each subsequent type. If none of them work, either the class is wrong, or it's a new response type you haven't yet made a class for.

Comment: Thanks! this helps!